# Custom Checkbox Button Issue

Tags: css, checkbox

I´m trying to make a custom checkbox buttons that when clicked on will change its color as an indicator that they are active. I got up the point where its almost done but the checkbox is appearing left of the box instead of being the button itself. I can't find out how to do this.

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
    width: auto;
    height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;    
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label {
    font-family: "Aharoni";
    display: inline-block;
    background: #dcdcdc;
    color: black;
    font-size: 12px;  
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
    border: solid 1px #a8a8a8;
    border-bottom-color: black;
    border-radius: 0px;
    width: auto;
    height: 20px;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
    cursor: pointer;    
    position: relative;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label,
input[type=checkbox]:active + label {
    background:gray;    
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="test" /><label>Text goes here</label></input>
```

Comment: Can you put the runnable script, so that it will be easy for us to analyze the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as follows it will solve your problem:

Add a `for` the attribute in the label and set an `id` attribute in the `input` type this will bind both the elements and you can get the desired result.

```
<input id="my_checkbox" type="checkbox" name="test" />
    <label for="my_checkbox">
         Text goes here
    </label>
</input>
```

Here I have put an `id="my_checkbox"` to the the checkbox input and added in the `for="my_checkbox"` attr.

Answer (score 0):

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
    width: auto;
    height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;    
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 9999;

}

input[type=checkbox] + label {
    font-family: "Aharoni";
    display: inline-block;
    background: #dcdcdc;
    color: black;
    font-size: 12px;  
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;

    border: solid 1px #a8a8a8;
    border-bottom-color: black;
    border-radius: 0px;

    width: auto;
    height: 20px;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
    cursor: pointer;    
    position: relative;

}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label,
input[type=checkbox]:active + label {
    background:gray;    
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="test"><label>Text goes here</label></input>
```